# How to open file in Windows while not blocking its renaming

Tags: windows, file

Is there a way to keep a file open, while not blocking its renaming by another application?

Keeping the file open does not block its renaming in Unix. Can I achieve the same behavior in Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to open your file with the sharing mode `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` (0x00000004).

See MSDN help for the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) API.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not. Windows handles open files very different from unix (under *ux you can even move or delete a file without interfering with an open handle). Maybe with a new filesystem its possible (try the ext3 filesystem driver for windows for example)